# Unable to access SQL Azure database using IP address?

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-sql-database, virtual-ip-address

Because of my `machine IP gets changed dynamically` (get ip using website  whatismyip.com ) I could `not able to access and set Server-Level Firewall Rules to sql azure database`.

> I tried to add range also 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 but it is not working.
>
> Is there any work around to access SQL Azure?

getting error:
[image]

Comment: You should add your external ip-address to the firewall, not your intranet ip-address. Check you external ip-address using a website like http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: I tried the same not working :( what should I enter in range ? for example my IP is `122.21.212.212`

Comment: Can it be that your firewall is just blocking SQL connections on port 1433?

Comment: i also think so , i have to confirm this from my Network team

Comment: I tried to add port in `sql server configuration manager` but still its of no use :(

Comment: @ashish Did you tried to connect to your Sql Database from a different PC in a different network/place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a post a while ago on how to access the SQL Azure instance using point-to-site VPN provided by Azure Virtual Network. It does not require anything to be open on the SQL Azure side. Here is a link to it: http://rtumaykin-it.blogspot.com/2015/01/using-linux-iptables-port-forwarding.html

Here is how to create a Virtual network and VPN: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

Hope this solution can help.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Azure requires you to add your public IP address to be added to restriction so that you can access it. Go to [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com) , fetch the address you get there and paste it in the Azure Management portal to the allowed IP List.